# The entity or complex type X cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Let's suppose I have a table Worker with the columns: CODE, NAME, LASTNAME.
I am trying to get just one value(the column CODE of the first row of my table) of one row of my table. 
I was trying to do it but it doesnt work:

```
        using (FactoryEntities FactoryDB = new FactoryEntities())
        {
            var code= FactoryDB.Worker
                .OrderBy(x => x.Code)
                .Select( x=>new Worker() {
                    Code=x.Code
                    }
                ).FirstOrDefault();

            return code;
        }
```

and I have read it in another post:

> You cannot (and should not be able to) project onto a mapped entity. You can, however, project onto an annonymous type or onto a DTO

Yes, I have used what He said when I needed to get a long list but in this case I think it is not useful to create an annonymous type just for one value (the column CODE of the first row).

So, how can i do to get just one value without creating a an annonymous type or a DTO.

Comment: If you only want a single property then you should be creating a DTO. Don't abuse the entity models for this purpose. If you really only want a single column, then return that value only. For example, if it's a string property, then return a string.

Comment: How can I do it? I dont get it at all

Comment: Well, just do `.Select( x=> x.Code)`

Comment: yes, it seems logical. I was confused because I started using annonymous types WorkerDTO that were used to map. I will try what you propose. Itried and it worked well, how can i vote up your comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply select just necessary field instead of creating the DTO, annonymous type and `Worker` type:

```
var code= FactoryDB.Worker
    .OrderBy(x => x.Code)
    .Select(x=> x.Code).FirstOrDefault();
```

It requires the less code and should construct the optimized `sql`

Comment: yes, it seems logical. I was confused because I started using annonymous types WorkerDTO that were used to map. I will try what you propose.